# Проблема при переопределении методов insertString и replace класса DocumentFilter

Tags: java, swing

В приведённом ниже коде происходит переопределение методов insertString и replace. Для нового фильтра IntFilter, который анализирует строку и вставляет только цифры и символ -:

```
JFormattedTextField intField3 = new 
                JFormattedTextField( new 
                InternationalFormatter( NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance())
                {
                    protected DocumentFilter getDocumentFilter() {                        
                        return filter;
                    }
                    private DocumentFilter filter = new IntFilter();
                } );        
        intField3.setValue( new Integer(100) );
```

Компилятор ругается на

```
super.insertString(fb, offset, builder.toString(), attr);
```

и

```
super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attr);
```

Пишет что:
cannot be applied to given types

Вот код класса IntFilter

```
package swingformattest;

    import java.lang.reflect.Array;
    import javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet;
    import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
    import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

    /**
     * Фильтр ограничивающий ввод цифрами и знаком минус
     * @author Igor
     */
    public class IntFilter extends DocumentFilter {
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string,
                                 AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( string );
            for ( int i = builder.length(); i >= 0; i-- ) {
                int cp = builder.codePointAt( i );            
                if ( !Character.isDigit(cp) && cp != '-' ) {                
                    builder.deleteCharAt( i );
                    if ( Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint( cp ) ) {
                        i--;
                        builder.deleteCharAt( i );
                    }                
                }
            }
            super.insertString(fb, offset, builder.toString(), attr);
        }
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String string,
                            AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException
        {
            if ( string != null ) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( string );
                for ( int i = builder.length(); i >= 0; i-- ) {
                int cp = builder.codePointAt( i );            
                if ( !Character.isDigit(cp) && cp != '-' ) {                
                    builder.deleteCharAt( i );
                    if ( Character.isSupplementaryCodePoint( cp ) ) {
                        i--;
                        builder.deleteCharAt( i );
                    }                
                }
            }
            }
            super.replace(fb, offset, length, string, attr);                
        }
    }
```

Этот пример взят из книги Хорстмана Java 2 Том 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы импортировали не тот `AttributeSet` :). Вам нужен

```
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
```

Негативная сторона автоимпорта IDE.